# Icon in jQueryMobile split listview is unresponsive in Firefox, while containing split item is not

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-mobile

I have a split listview

```
+---------------------+--------+
|                     |wwwwwwww|
| listview entry      |w icon w|
|                     |wwwwwwww|
+---------------------+--------+
```

that can be pared down to [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXBcV/1/). There's a button on the right hand side, bound to a function. The button is an icon surrounded by its default white border (indicated with 'w').

What I expect:

- the function gets called (duh). Either if I click on the icon, or if I click on the white space (since it's all generated by the same A entity), regardless of the browser.

What I get:

- Working as expected in Chrome 30.0.1599.69m.
- Working as expected in Firefox 24.0, **if I click on the white space w**
- Firefox, clicking *exactly on the icon*, the button changes state (so the system is aware of the click!); but **my function doesn't seem to get called**.

This does not happen (not even in Firefox) if I use a default button with `href`. For example [the original basic fiddle by Gajotres](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nwg5b/) works without a hitch. But I need to bind a function and I'd like to do this with `on()`.

While researching on the triggering stuff, I found [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2390-Tracing-Event-Binding-And-Event-Triggering-In-jQuery.htm), which while not working for me, pointed me in the right direction:

> Ironically, it actually turned out to be a CSS issue (with Z-index), not an event issue;

so that I could devise a workaround (the line is commented in the code; just uncomment it and click "run" again).

Is this a bug in jQuery(Mobile)? Or in Firefox? Or, which somehow seems more likely, it's just that **[I'm doing it wrong](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/john-mccarthy-programming-wrong.jpg)**?

Comment: the weird thing, is when you change `click` with `mouseup` or `mousedown`, it works http://jsfiddle.net/RXBcV/3/ Although, on those events, z-index of all elements wrapped in `.foo` dont change http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mRqzw/

Comment: both demos were tested on FF and Chrome latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Temporary answer

*Apparently* this is a bug in Firefox and jQM not agreeing on objects' creation order when the A button isn't "standard". The z-index of the icon is wrong, and the object intercepts the click and doesn't let it bubble, so that the button itself hears nothing.

By adding a z-index correction [as per fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXBcV/2/), Firefox behaviour returns to normal.

```
$(".foo")
.off("click")
.on("click", function() {
    alert("ok");
    return false;
})
.find("span.ui-btn-inner").css("z-index", "-1")
```

or simply blanket-hit those pesky inner button icon spans:

```
$("a.ui-li-link-alt span.ui-btn-inner").css("z-index", "-1")
```

**IMPORTANT**: this "solution" does not address the real problem (be it a bug, or stupidity on my part), so it can't be relied upon to work e.g. in future versions of jQuery/jQM.